# MacBook Pro - Internal SSD No Longer Bootable

Tags: macos, mac, ssd

I installed OS X Yosemite onto an external SSD by downloading it through the App Store, running the installer, and choosing the external drive as the target. After the install, which worked fine as far as I can tell, my internal SSD is no longer bootable and is not recognized as having OS X.

I removed and connected the internal drive to another computer and confirmed that the data is still there. When I try to run it alone as an internal drive, the OS X installer comes up every time.

I would appreciate help figuring out:

1. Why this happened?
2. What should I do now?
3. If I install OS X back onto the drive, will it delete all the data and settings and applications?

Comment: I'm not a Mac expert, but, there should be some visible bootable images on the SSD to know that the OS is present. When loading BIOS, do you have an option to select BOOT option? If so, check if the Mac OS is available in this list. What's changed recently that might affect this?

Comment: @AaronLayfield It's an Intel Mac and I don't believe it has bios nor open firmware :(